# Snowplow stopped worked on iOS after upgrading Capacitor

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor, snowplow

My Ionic app uses Snowplow javascript tracker and it's been working fine for both Android and iOS, with my currently version of Capacitor (3.0). When migrating to Capacitor 4, it stopped working for iOS, while still works normally for Android. Would anyone have any idea why? I followed the Ionic documentation for the migration.

I tried to upgrade the snowplow version (from 3.3 to 3.15) and no success.